# Trying to make a small ncurses app, but error: expressions are not allowed at the top level

Tags: swift

In following instructions from [iachievedit](http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/ncurses-with-swift-on-linux/) and using [mccuneware](https://github.com/mccuneware/CNCURSES)'s ncurses package I cant make the following code run without an error.

```
import Foundation
import CNCURSES
import Glibc

enum Signal:Int32 {
case INT   = 2
case WINCH = 28
}

typealias SignalHandler = __sighandler_t

func trap(signum:Signal, action:SignalHandler) {
  signal(signum.rawValue, action)
}

trap(.INT) { signal in
  endwin()
  exit(0)
}

initscr()
noecho()    // Turn on noecho, though it doesn't matter in this example
curs_set(0) // 0 is invisible, 1 is visible, 2 is very visible

move(0, 0)
addstr("UL")
refresh() // This is required to update the screen
move(23,78)
addstr("LR")
refresh()

select(0, nil, nil, nil, nil) // Wait
```

The error is:

```
Compile Swift Module 'ncurses' (1 sources)
/home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Coding/Swift/ncurses/Sources/ncurses.swift:17:1: error: expressions are not allowed at the top level
initscr()
^
```

The directory structure is:

ncurses/Package.swift

ncurses/Sources/ncurses.swift

And the aforementioned CNCURSES is called within Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:3.1

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ncurses",  
    dependencies: [
    .Package(url:  "https://github.com/mccuneware/CNCURSES", majorVersion:1),
  ]
)
```

Seems to me that the instructions are outdated, but how to circumvent the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions cannot be at the top level of the module indeed. You have to write these in a `main.swift` file, this is what the compiler expects. The `main.swift` file is the entry point of your program execution.

To be precise: the file containing root-level instructions has to be named `main.swift`, not anything else; other files can exist, of course, but they cannot have top level instructions.

Comment: It is in the main.swift file, I will update the question with the directory structure.

Comment: Yes, the point is that the file containing root-level instructions *has to* be named `main.swift`, not anything else. Other files can exist but they cannot have top level instructions. :)